# Recreating 1980s graphic design

Tags: website-design, color, style, inspiration

I have noticed a recent move towards, or back towards, the colours and design elements of 1980s pop music videos. Neon pinks, blues and yellows. This has been happening a lot on TV but I haven't noticed it on many websites yet.

I have a white website that I would like to 'paint' with 80s pop style design with a modern twist. Could any one point me to any good examples of this or some resources that I may be able to use, or perhaps you could just share your opinions.

Comment: Google seems like the best place to point you at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this a couple of days ago on [Designer News](https://www.designernews.co/):

[Circles Conference 2016 by Circles Co.](http://circlesconference.com/)

Comment: love everything about that website. I know you aren't meant to say thank you, but thankyou so much. love it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look what people draw with tag "80s" and "1980" here:

https://dribbble.com/search?q=80s

https://dribbble.com/search?q=1980